# DBeaver - Funcionamiento inesperado del commit al editar componentes

Tags: postgresql

Buenas tardes, instalé hace 2 días la última versión de DBeaver (4.2.5). Antes tenía la 4.0.1.
Tengo una conexión a una base PostgreSQL.
Cada vez que abro el contenido de una tabla me pide hacer "Commit" o "Rollback".
Sin embargo, abro un SP, lo modifico, lo salvo (Ctrl-S), y hace auto-commit.
En las propiedades de la conexión, en "General", la opción "Auto-commit" está sin marcar.
Esto en la versión 4.0.1 no me pasaba.
Agradezco si tienen alguna idea al respecto.
Diego.

Comment: Solo para tenerlo claro, ¿cual es la parte que funcionaba diferentemente en la versión 4.0.1?

Comment: Ambas, Cuando editaba una tabla, sin modificarla, no me pedía Commit. Cuando cambiaba un SP, me pedía Commit.

Comment: Ninguna solución o comentario?